# Am I creating the class correctly?

Tags: c#, json, class, json.net

I am creating a JSON file to store the template details. Each template has several pages, each page has several areas and coordination.

### Template

```
[
  {
    Template_Name: "ABC",
    Page_Number: [
      {
        Page_Details: [
          { areaName: "xxxx", coordiante: "xxxx" },
          { areaName: "xxxx", coordiante: "xxxx" },
        ],
      },
      {
        Page_Details: [
          { areaName: "xxxx", coordinate: "xxxx" },
          { areaName: "xxxx", coordinate: "xxxx" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Below is the class of Template

```
class List<Template>
{
    public string tempName { get; set; }
    public List<pageNumber> pages { get; set; }
    public List<pageDetails> pagesDetails { get; set; }

    public class pageNumber
    {

    }

    public class pageDetails
    {
        public List<string> areaName { get; set; }
        public List<string> Coordinate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Am i doing it correctly?

Now, I trying to assign the value for it but it cannot work.

What I have tried:

```
 Template temp = new Template();
        PageDetail pgDetails = new PageDetail();
        PageNumber pgNumber = new PageNumber();

        temp.TemplateName = "ABC";
        pgDetails.AreaName = "xxx";
        pgDetails.Coordinate = "yyy";
        pgNumber.PageDetails.Add(pgDetails);



        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);
        MessageBox.Show(temp.ToString());
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I feel like `pageNumber` is missing something.

Comment: "Am i doing it correctly" How should *we* know? Does the code do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know if you are able to use your class to deserialize the sample json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [QuickType app](https://app.quicktype.io/) (not affiliated, just a fan) to quickly convert an example JSON into a class.

For your input, the output is (with that `coordiante` typo fixed):

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class ImageData
    {
        [JsonProperty("Template_Name")]
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Page_Number")]
        public List<PageNumber> PageNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PageNumber
    {
        [JsonProperty("Page_Details")]
        public List<PageDetail> PageDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PageDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("areaName")]
        public string AreaName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("coordinate")]
        public string Coordinate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool stuff, much better than the 'paste JSON as Classes' functionality of Visual Studio. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks AKX, but now I have some trouble in assigning the values for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not quite valid (trailing commas, and property names should have double-quote marks round them), but a tolerant de-serialiser like NewtsonSoft.JSON will let you off.

But the real problem is that your C# class structure makes very little sense in relation to the JSON (which you could have proved yourself by trying to test it). The property names mostly don't match those in the JSON and you've got quite confused about lists and objects and so on.

This structure would work:

```
public class PageDetail
{
    public string areaName { get; set; }
    public string coordiante { get; set; }
    public string coordinate { get; set; }
}

public class PageNumber
{
    public List<PageDetail> Page_Details { get; set; }
}

public class Template
{
    public string Template_Name { get; set; }
    public List<PageNumber> Page_Number { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could write

```
List<Template> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Template>>(json);
```

to convert your JSON text into a C# variable (assuming that `json` contains the data read from the file).

Demo (using a static string): https://dotnetfiddle.net/qCaeUg

Credit (with a slight tweak) to the conversion site http://json2csharp.com/